# combine values of several objects into a single dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am fetching these rows from db:

```
blog_id='12', field_name='title', translation='title12 in en', lang='en'
blog_id='12', field_name='desc', translation='desc12 in en', lang='en'

blog_id='13', field_name='title', translation='title13 in en', lang='en'
blog_id='13', field_name='desc', translation='desc13 in en', lang='en'
....
```

and I want to build a single dictionary for each blog_id: e.g.

```
[
   {'blog': '12', 'title': 'title12 in en', 'desc': 'desc12 in en'},
   {'blog': '13', 'title': 'title13 in en', 'desc': 'desc13 in en'},
   ....
]
```

I am trying this way:

```
res = []
dict_ = {}
for trans in translations: # 'translations' is QuerySet, already filtered by 'en'  
    if trans.blog_id in dict_.values():
        dict_[trans.field_name] = trans.translation
    else:
        dict_['blog'] = trans.blog_id
        dict_[trans.field_name] = trans.translation

    res.append(dict_)
```

but this is soo wrong, `res` contains here `blog 13` 3 times and `blog 12` isnot even in the final list. I feel so dumb right now, what am I missing?

Comment: You are adding the same dictionary object to `res`, you are not even creating new dict objects

Comment: @thefourtheye I know :( I need to create new dict dynamically somehow on the way...

Comment: why not use the `blog_id` as an outer key and create a dict of dicts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, accumulate all the data corresponding to every `blog_id` in a dictionary, like this

```
groups = {}
for trans in translations:
  groups.setdefault(trans.blog_id, {})[trans.field_name] = trans.translation
```

Now, attach the corresponding `blog_id` to all the accumulated dictionaries,

```
for key in groups:
  groups[key]['blog'] = key
```

Now, just get all the `values` of the `groups`, with `groups.values()` to get the result.

**Note:** If you want to retain the original order of elements based on the `blog_id`, then instead of using a normal dictionary, use `collections.OrderedDict`, like this

```
from collections import OrderedDict
groups = OrderedDict()
...
```